# how to get button title using for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
        //here   take a array with letters 
        _englishArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
        int i=0;
        float x=5,y=13;
        //add array elements as button title
        for (i=0; i< [_englishArray count]; i++) {
            button.tag=i+1;
            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [button setTitle:[_englishArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            button.frame= CGRectMake(x, y, 29, 30);
            button.titleLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
            x= x+31;
            if (x==320 || x>310) {
                x=5;
                y=y+40;
            }
            [_keyboardImageView addSubview:button];
        }


        //   and i add the each button to _keyboardImageView and set title as _english arry elements ...and the get buttons curren title for this code...
    //here get the button title useing for loop

   for (int j=0;j<=[_englishArray count]; j++) {
   //  here get button from image view by useing tag
            butt = (UIButton *)[_keyboardImageView viewWithTag:j+1];
            NSLog(@"%@",butt.titleLabel.text);
        }
```

it prints null not give button title............
Note:i am using `button.currentitle` also
how is it possible..why its displays null?

Comment: "how to get button title using for loop" - like this: `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { NSString *t = button.title; }`

Comment: Assigning a tag to a button without even creating/allocating it, is of no sense. That's why `viewWithTag:` is failing miserably.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the title with `setTitle:forState:`, use `titleForState:` to get the title:

```
NSLog(@"title is %@", [butt titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
```

Of course this assumes that `butt` isn't `nil`. You need to assign the button's tag after you allocate the button:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.tag=i+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define   your button in for loop like

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and than specify tag.

```
   button.tag=i+1;
```

You have to define button in for loop instead of .h file.

And for get title text

```
      for (int j=0;j<=[_englishArray count]; j++) {
  UIButton  *butt = (UIButton *)[_keyboardImageView viewWithTag:j+1];
    NSLog(@"%@",butt.titleLabel.text);
}
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
_englishArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
int i=0;
float x=5,y=13;
//add array elements as button title
for (i=0; i< [_englishArray count]; i++) {
    button.tag=i+1;
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button.frame= CGRectMake(x, y, 29, 30);
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [button setTitle:[_englishArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //button.titleLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    [_keyboardImageView addSubview:button];
    x= x+31;
    if (x==320 || x>310) {
        x=5;
        y=y+40;
    }

}

//here get the button title useing for loop
//   and i add the each button to _keyboardImageView and set title as _english arry elements ...and the get buttons curren title for this code....
for (int j=0;j<=[_englishArray count]; j++) {
    butt = (UIButton *)[_keyboardImageView viewWithTag:j+1];
    NSLog(@"Required Result is %@",butt.titleLabel.text);


}
```

Try it ,it will work...

Comment: It simply won't because it is assigning a tag to a button without even allocating it, so `viewWithTag:` for this purpose won't work.